# How get the last element in the table in the relationship in an efficient way?

Tags: nestjs, mikro-orm

let's say I have an entity called `user` and each user has many `accounts`, and I want to get the last account inserted in a specific user.

I tried different solutions but I didn't find a better one, I had to get a user and then use `loadItems` method with `orderBy` desc and then get first element but I don't want to load all accounts from DB.

that's what I did

```
const user = await this.repository.find({id})
const accounts = await user.accounts.loadItems({orderBy: {['column']: 'DESC'}})

return accounts[0];
```

that's absolutely not a good solution because I load all items from the database first, is there any other way to do it? I'm still new in MikroOrm so I'll appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are many options:

- use `em.findOne` to load just the right entity (e.g. `em.findOne(Account, { user })`)
- use `user.accounts.matching` that has a `limit` option: https://mikro-orm.io/docs/collections#filtering-collections
- if you want to do this for many entities and not just one, use SQL sub query via `@Formula` decorator: https://mikro-orm.io/docs/defining-entities#formulas